# How to test Angular Material template variable with Storybook

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook, nx-workspace

Here is my template:

```
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 1</button>
  <button mat-menu-item>Item 2</button>
</mat-menu>
```

it's works fine with angular page. I am trying to test in `storybook` no menu displays. I am importing `Material module` with `storybook` but no result. anything else need to added? or how can i test with storybook. any help?

I am working in `Nx worksapce` I am trying to test my library.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add the browser module. it works fine after. here is the updated code:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from '@hf-workspace/material';
import { Meta, moduleMetadata, Story } from '@storybook/angular';
import { LinkListComponent } from './link-list.component';

export default {
  title: 'LinkListComponent',
  component: LinkListComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      imports: [MaterialModule, BrowserAnimationsModule],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta<LinkListComponent>;

const Template: Story<LinkListComponent> = (args: LinkListComponent) => ({
  props: args,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {};
```